# Compare tables in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]Suppose i have a table with a user's favorites books. Is it possible through SQL commands check the other user who has the most favorites books in common with the first user? I've thought about assigning a variable that counts the number of times a certain book appears in a user favorites books and repeat that for the other users tables but I think it would take a lot of time. **EDIT**: in the attached picture there's a comparison of user's favorite musics (books was just another example). Suppose these were the two users with most musics in common, how would I compose a query to find them?

Comment: Please provide some ddl+dml for sample data, and also what rdbms?

Comment: Just added Zohar Peled, sorry for the poor explanation..

Comment: To translate those acronyms: please show us the structure of your tables, and perhaps some sample data. It also matters which type of database you are using - MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc. Please edit these details into the question, don't try to fit them in comments.

Comment: Please do not post sample data as screenshots. At least use formatted text that can be copied. Even better post `create table` and `insert` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of favorites in common between two users, use a self-join with aggregation:

```
select b1.userid as user1, b2.userid as user2, count(*) as inCommon
from favourites b1 inner join
     favourites b2 
     on b2.bookid = b1.bookid
where b1.userid <> b2.userid
group by b1.userid, b2.userid;
```

To get the users that have the most books in common, use `rank()` or `row_number()` window functions:

```
select bb.*
from (select b1.userid as user1, b2.userid as user2, count(*) as inCommon,
             rank() over (partition by b1.userid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from favourites b1 inner join
           favourites b2 
           on b2.bookid = b1.bookid
      where b1.userid <> b2.userid
      group by b1.userid, b2.userid
    ) bb
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you only need the value for one user, then you can just use `limit` and `order by` on the first query:

```
select b1.userid as user1, b2.userid as user2, count(*) as inCommon
from favourites b1 inner join
     favourites b2 
     on b2.bookid = b1.bookid
where b1.userid <> b2.userid and b1.userid = 1
group by b1.userid, b2.userid
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases to join the table to itself, you can join on the bookid to return a list of users that have the same favourite book. For example:

```
select 
b1.username,
b2.username
from favourites b1
inner join favourites b2 on b2.bookid = b1.bookid
where
b1.username <> b2.username
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match against one specific user you can use this approach:

```
select 
   b2.username as OtherUser, -- matching user
   COUNT(b2.bookid) as OtherUserMatchesCount -- number of matches for the other user
from favourites b1
join favourites b2 
  on b1.bookid = b2.bookid -- they both like the same book
where b1.username = 'MATT' -- match against user 'MATT'
  and b1.username <> b2.username -- of course exclude 'MATT'
group by
   b2.username
order by COUNT(b2.bookid) DESC -- best matches on top
-- add LIMIT 1?
```